# What are the chances of someone coming up with a new and simple/out-of-the-box solution for the double-spending problem?

Tags: bitcoin-core, ripple, doublespend, proof-of-work, consensus

The proof-of-work solution is simple but has many drawbacks (waste of time, energy and uncertainties about its security in the future).

The consensus solutions proposed by Ripple/Stellar are too complex, and with complexity also comes uncertainty/risk. (See Stellar catastrophic failure!)

What do you think are the chances of someone coming with a simpler solution, out of the box, something much more straightforward that no-one has thought about it?

Comment: Ripple is effectively completely centralized.

Comment: @Bitcoin That doesn't really act as an example of why it *can't* be done, because avoiding centralization was never one of the goals of Ripple.

Comment: @NickODell Mostly pointing out that Ripple/Stellar being complex isn't an argument against it being a replacement decentralized consensus.

Answer (score 3):

The double-spending problem had been unsolved in decentralized protocols for decades. It seems unlikely that a second (different) solution would suddenly materialize.

It never was a problem in centralized setups, where the central entity would provide a referee function.

Comment: Didn't ripple do it? Not going into the merit of if it is better or worse, but it is an alternative solution, correct?

Comment: Quoting Bitcoin (the stackexchange user) : "Ripple is effectively completely centralized. –  Bitcoin Sep 4 at 8:21". Your question doesn't make sense of you allow for centralized solutions, so I'm assuming you're asking about a decentralized solution.

Comment: @Jannes You are correct. For a centralized solution the double-spending problem does not make any sense. So what is all the hype around ripple? Did they solve the double-spending solution or not?

Comment: They're just trying to hijack the bitcoin success to promote their own stuff. Up to the point of claiming with a straight face that it is decentralized. You see that a lot in bitcoin space, or any space where money is involved. Always beware of the vultures.